# how to make a code::blocks project for caffe

Tags: c++, codeblocks, caffe

I like to have a code::blocks project out of the sources of the caffe framework.
I checked out the whole repository from caffe and made the makefile.config and all the stuff and already build caffe with make. Till now I used caffe only as a black-box and were fine with that.
But now I like get some deeper knowledge of what happens inside and my first step is to make a proper project for the Code::Blocks IDE.
I read that it is possible to generate project-files with cmake and those cmake-generators (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#cmake-generators and https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/generator/CodeBlocks.html). But I'm not so familiar with the settings and parameter for cmake and need some help.
I'm developing on Ubuntu 15.04-64bit. If you need some further information add a comment and I'll edit the post.

Comment: Code::Blocks is junk. You should look at https://www.geany.org/

Comment: Why that? C::B is cross OS, thats nice. Actually it was not the question, to start a discussion on C::B ;-)